# Link specific time of video hosted in Google Cloud

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I have a video hosted on a Google Cloud bucket that can be publicly accessed. I've previously been able to host a video on Google Drive and create a link that would start playing the video from a specific timestamp (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99936/is-there-a-way-to-link-to-a-specific-position-inside-a-video-on-google-drive)

How can I do a similar thing with Google Cloud videos? Adding ?t=XXs to the end of the URL does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Storage links aren't actually streaming video.  They're just downloading the file, and the browser is playing it as the file content is downloaded. So you won't be able to seek to a specific time by simply specifying a time in the query string.  If you want true video streaming with seeking and adaption to the speed of the connection, you should use a video streaming service.

Comment: Is there any plan to support streaming from GCS in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage is where you have saved your video on the cloud. Depending on your app's programming language, there are tools available to you by google client library for that language where you can determine the starting point of video stream. For example, if you use `Node.js` the following code will start the video from a specific start to end point within video.

```
let f = fs.createReadStream("myVideo.mp4", {start, end});
```

Comment: Which library? In the node.js `fs` library, `start` is an offset in bytes and not a time value.

Comment: Wouldn't the time be proportional to the bytes?

Comment: This isn't really how video streaming works.  You can't just seek into a byte location and expect it to start playing whatever is there.  Also, `fs` works with files on the filesystem (hence the name `fs`), so it's not going to help with files being downloaded directly from Storage, which is the issue here.

Comment: The point here is not the actual Nodejs or python solution or how to use a HTML5 video element, it's the fact any such solution need to be implemented on the client/app side and not the cloud storage side.